# Уведомления о новых сообщениях

Tags: node.js

Подскажите, как реализовать уведомления о непрочитанных сообщениях на Node.js + socket.io?
У каждого пользователя есть список диалогов, необходимо, чтобы диалог, в котором пришло новое сообщение, поднимался наверх и был выделен другим цветом.

Answer (score 2):

Подключаете библиотеку и подписываетесь на событие:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('message', function (messageData) {
      PickUpDialog(messageData.dialogID);
  });
</script>
```

А на сервере делаете emit, когда приходит новое сообщение.

[socket.io docs](http://socket.io/#how-to-use)